# Flexible customelements with Polymer in a row for different devices ( using media-queries )

Tags: html, cordova, polymer

Let's say i have

```
<template is="dom-repeat" id="places" items="{{ data }}" as="place" index-as="placeCount"  layout horizontal>             
      <place-list-item flex title="{{place.title}}" image="{{place.image}}" description="Random text to display">
       </place-list-item>
</template>
```

I determine the screen layout with :

```
<iron-media-query query="(min-width: 422px)" query-matches="{{ isSmall }}"></iron-media-query>
<iron-media-query query="(min-width: 642px)" query-matches="{{ isMedium }}"></iron-media-query>
<iron-media-query query="(min-width: 1202px)" query-matches="{{ isLarge }}"></iron-media-query>
<iron-media-query query="(orientation: landscape)" query-matches="{{ landscape }}"></iron-media-query>
<iron-media-query query="(orientation: portrait)" query-matches="{{ portrait }}"></iron-media-query>
```

What's the proper way to style this using Polymer 1.0 when i want 2 custom elements when the screen is small and 3 custom elements when the screen is large.

I was thinking about wrapping divs in the loop, but it doesn't look really clean

```
<template is="dom-if" if="{{ show(placeCount, isSmall, isMedium, isLandscape, isPortrait, isLandscape) }}">
    <div>
</template>
```

With the following unfinished script

```
    show: function (index,isSmall, isMedium, isLarge, isPortrait, isLandscape) { 
        console.log(index, isSmall, isMedium, isLandscape, isPortrait, isLandscape);
        return index % 2 == 0;
    },
```

Any thoughts?

PS. I also use cordova

PS2. I also tried styling the width with max-width={{determineWidth}}% where the scripts calculates the max width per element, it should look like this :

```
(100-placesInRow) / placesInRow; //but it wouldn't bind :)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When using  items, they all stamp their contents and prepend the template's contents outside of the template itself. So, surrounding the content of your dom-if with a tag would be the quickest way to set width of the content.

Setting width using max-width=, your script should return (100-placesInRow) / placesInRow + "%" and leave off the % in the attribute value.

I am a little confused as to what you are trying to do with the 2 vs 3 items and doing it in this way. if you know 2 items at one res and 3 at another, use a calculated value for the dom-repeat's items attribute to return 2 or 3 items.

Comment: I'm displaying 2 elements in a row for smaller screens and portrait orientation and 3 elements for smaller screens in landscape orientation ( additional changes for medium screens / larger screens are coming, but i wanted a cleaner solution before i executed it)

Comment: While calculating the appropriate width would definitely work, my personal opinion is to solve this purely with CSS. Set a max and min-width for the place-list-item and give the list a wrapping tag, where you set the width of 2*place-list-item or 3*place-list-item depending on the media query. Much better maintainability and separation of style and code...

Comment: I concur. Use CSS along with horizontal layouts and you should be able to achieve the effects you are looking for with a much better visual result.